# Simple PHP random array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array like this:

```
$input = array('Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3');
```

And want to echo one of the values randomly. I've done this before but can't remember how I did it and all the examples of array_rand seem more complex that what I need.

Can any help? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
echo $input[array_rand($input)];
```

[array_rand()](https://www.php.net/array_rand) returns the key, so we need to plug it back into `$input` to get the value.

Comment: how do we show a just one result that is random?

Answer (score 4):

*Complex?* Are we on the same [manual page](http://www.php.net/array_rand)?

```
$rand_key = array_rand($input, 1);
```

Comment: No the examples on php.net were over the top for what I wanted when all I wanted was something simple.

Comment: @Cameron that's intended: That is the array key. Use `$input[$rand_key]` to access the element

Comment: If *0* is the selected random key, it is the selected random key. Whats the matter with that?

Comment: Would it be possible to make sure a different value is shown each time? So almost rotating them but in a random order.

Answer (score 3):

You could use shuffle() and then just pick the first element.

```
shuffle($input);
echo $input[0];
```

But I would go with the array_rand() method.

Answer (score 2):

`array_rand` will help you select a random key of an array. From there you can get the value.

```
$randKey = array_rand($input);
echo $input[$randKey];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a single function: [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

```
echo $input[array_rand($input,1)];
```

Comment: The example above by waiwai933 doesn't have the 1 but outputs the same as your code. what does the 1 do?

Comment: @Cameron look into the manual. `If you are picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, it returns an array of keys for the random entries. This is done so that you can pick random keys as well as values out of the array.`

Comment: The *1* as second argument is the default value, so you can omit it.